# write system call in C, how to print integer value to file

Tags: c, file, integer, system-calls

I'm tring to write an variable to a file, but I keep getting syntax errors or it doesn't prints it to the file.

I have info.uptime, and I want to print it to "file.txt", so I tried:

```
int fd = open("file.txt", O_WRONLY);
write(fd, info.uptime, length(info.uptime));
```

The length fucntion is function that I created to see the length of the number.
At the file the numbers are gone, so I tried:

```
int fd = open("file.txt", O_WRONLY);
write(fd,("%lu" ,info.uptime), length(info.uptime));
```

Now it gives me syntax error too many arguments.
How should I do it?

*it's on ubuntu*

EDIT: I can ONLY use:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include "helper.h"
```

EDIT2:

```
int length(int n)
{
        int i;
    for (i=0;n>=1;i++)
    {
        n = n/10;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: you first go probably worked but wrote the data as binary. We dont know how 'length' works so its impossible to say if it really worked or not

Comment: Note: for `length(0)`, suggest `for (i=0;n>=0;i++)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong. Type:

```
man -s 3 write
```

From a command line.

---

**Edit**: Answer no longer makes sense as question was updated to use the correct syntax.

Comment: also apt-get install build-essential

Answer (score 0):

you are wanting the system to work how you want it. Ie just wishing functions into existence because they are useful. There is no write function that accepts a file name. There is no write function that accepts a printf format string as its second argument.

You need

```
fopen(<name>)
fprintf(...)
fclose
```

after your edit to add open you are still wishing into existence functions that dont exist (write that takes printf). If you want to write as string you will have to convert it yourself if you can't use itoa or xprintf

Answer (score 0):

your edit2 shows that you almost have it working. Mix in a little

```
char digit = n%10
```

in the loop and you'll be done. DO you want us to actually just write the code for you. Its really cs101 level stuff